# Javascript Replace Function with jQuery Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework, jquery-events

I have a Javascript function that, when called, displays the CSS div  `#mapLoading` and appends the style `display:block`. The line of code which completes this action is as follows:

### **Code #1**

```
 mapLoading.style.display = "block";
```

The function in its entirety is shown at the bottom of this question.

---

I also have the following jQuery code which appends the CSS class `.weareloading` when the element is hovered on with the mouse, then removes the class `.weareloading` once the CSS3 animations (rotate and fadeIn) complete.

### **Code #2**

```
$("#mapLoading").hover(function(){
  $(this).addClass("weareloading");})
$("#mapLoading").bind("webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd animationEnd", function(){
  $(this).removeClass("weareloading")  
})
```

---

What I'd like to do - and the reason for this question - is the following:

- Replace **Code #1** with **Code #2** in the Javascript function
- Remove the mouse hovering requirement in **Code #2** so that the function displayed below simply adds the class `.weareloading` then removes the class `.weareloading` once the animations are complete.

Unfortunately, the entire program is complex and holds many files, so I can't provide a live example on jsFiddle. However, here is the above-referenced Javascript function that should hopefully provide enough context for this question:

*Line 2 contains Code #1*

```
function doSearch(keyword, type) {
 mapLoading.style.display = "block";
  currentCategory = type;
  var icon;

        if (markerGroups[type]) {

        for (var i = 0; i < markerGroups[type].length; i++) {
          markerGroups[type][i].setMap(null);
        }
        markerGroups[type].length = 0;
        }


  if (keyword.substr(0,3) == "db:"){ 
  var bounds = map.getBounds();
  var southWest = bounds.getSouthWest();
  var northEast = bounds.getNorthEast();
  var swLat = southWest.lat();
  var swLng = southWest.lng();
  var neLat = northEast.lat();
  var neLng = northEast.lng();
  var dbCat = keyword.substr(3);

  var filename = dbPath + "db.php?cat="+ dbCat + "&swLat="+ swLat + "&swLng="+ swLng + "&neLat="+ neLat + "&neLng="+ neLng + "&extendLat="+ extendLat + "&extendLng="+ extendLng;
    $.getJSON(filename, function(data) {
   var hider = document.getElementById(type).getAttribute("caption");
    if (hider != "hidden") {
        for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
            var result = data.results[i];
                if (result.icon === "" ) {
                    icon = type;
                } else {
                    icon = result.icon;
                }
            cleanHTML = html_entity_decode(result.html);
            var xmlHTML = createXmlHTML(result.address, result.name, cleanHTML, result.url, result.geometry.location.lat, result.geometry.location.lng);
            var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(result.geometry.location.lat), parseFloat(result.geometry.location.lng));
            createMarker(latlng, i, xmlHTML, type, icon, "db", result.name);
      }
  }
     mapLoading.style.display = "none";
});

  } else {
                var hider = document.getElementById(type).getAttribute("caption");
                if (type == "user") {
                var userName = document.getElementById(type).getAttribute("name");
                    if (userName === null) {
                            hider = "hidden";
                    } else {
                        keyword = "establishment";
                        searchName = userName;
                    }
                }
                if (hider != "hidden") {
                var searchName = document.getElementById(type).getAttribute("name");
                if (searchName === null){
                    searchName = "";
                } else {
                    searchName = "&name=" + searchName;
                }
                    var ctr = map.getCenter();
                    //alert("Center: " + ctr)
                    var jsonLAT = ctr.lat();
                    var jsonLNG = ctr.lng();
                    if (autoRadius === true){
                        searchRadius = distance( map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lat(), map.getBounds().getNorthEast().lng(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lat(), map.getBounds().getSouthWest().lng());
                    }
                    var JSON = dbPath + "jsonproxy.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=" + jsonLAT + "," + jsonLNG + "&radius=" + searchRadius + "&types=" + keyword + searchName + "&sensor=false");
                    $.getJSON(JSON, function(data) {
                            for (i = 0; i < data.results.length; i++) {
                              var result = data.results[i];
                              var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(result.geometry.location.lat), parseFloat(result.geometry.location.lng));
                              var resultHTML = "api:" + result.reference;
                              createMarker(latlng, i, resultHTML, type, type, "api", result.name, result.icon);
                              if (hider == "hidden") {
                                markerGroups[type][i].hide();
                              }
                            }
                               mapLoading.style.display = "none";
                    });
                }
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first part is simple, change line 2 of the function to:

```
$("#mapLoading").addClass("weareloading");
```

I can't see where in your function you're doing the animation, so I'm not sure where to remove the class. If you're using jQuery animation functions, they should have a callback that gets called when the animation is complete. In this callback function, put:

```
$("#mapLoading").removeClass("weareloading");
```

BTW, since you're using jQuery, why do you have all that verbose raw JavaScript? E.g. why:

```
document.getElementById(type).getAttribute("caption");
```

when it could be:

```
$('#'+type).attr("caption");
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thank you much for the answer. The reason for all the raw Javascript is that I am slowly converting the entire program to use jQuery coding, but I'm also having to learn jQuery at the same time. Got hung up a bit on this part, so thank you again for the answer!